# PDF creation and email on clicking submit

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a checkbox list for the products to selected, with another text entry for quantity. Upon clicking Submit, I need two actions to be performed:
1) I would like to get the customers selection and entry into an email (with a given email address) and emailed as a (create) PDF attachment with date-time stamp.
2) The next page after hitting submit button, should produce next/another page with email confirmation message and a print button of the PDF attachment with date-time stamp.
There are many other things that go into this webform, but this is the area that I am needing some guidance and any link or code example to help me find a proper solution you can reply me here would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For PDF creation, there are several tools- I've used iTextSharp. You can download the nuget package on VS and example code can be found [here](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/80/create-pdfs-in-asp-net-getting-started-with-itextsharp). You will probably want to use tables to make it look nice, but to get used to it, maybe just throw some info in to get an idea of how it works.

The method may look something like this:

```
public byte[] CreateOrderPdf(OrderDetails details)
{
    byte[] fileBytes;
    using (MemoryStream PdfStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        iTextSharp.text.Document doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document();
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, PdfStream);

        doc.Open(); 
        doc.Add(new Paragraph(OrderDetails.Name));
        doc.Add(new Paragraph(OrderDetails.Address)); 
        //Add More Tables and Content Here (See Documentation for more)

        doc.Close();
        fileBytes = PdfStream.ToArray(); 
    }
    return fileBytes
}
```

For Email, .Net has the [System.Net.Mail.MailMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage(v=vs.110).aspx) class. You can attach the pdf as a stream. You will need to define the to, from, subject, body, etc. That would look something like this:

```
string fileName = string.Format("OrderConfirmation-{0}.pdf", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-dd-M--HH-mm-ss")); 
MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);
message.Subject = subject;
message.Body = body;

MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(fileBytes);    
stream.Position = 0; 
Attachment attachment = new Attachment(stream, fileName, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
message.Attachments.Add(attachment);

SmtpClient mailServer = new SmtpClient(example.stmphost.com);
mailserver.Send(message);

message.Dispose();
```

Hopefully this is a good starting point for you.

Comment: Great info Aaron! Thx!

Answer (score 0):

In my search of the solution and suggested starting point, I stumbled upon this and I will also MENTION this for anyone looking for the same answers to look into spire.pdf at www.e-iceblue.com/Introduce/pdf-for-net-introduce.html